# Logical if difference

Tags: javascript, php, typescript

Recently, I came across a code like this:

```
if (0 === $something) { }
```

Is there any difference between the code above with:

```
if ($something === 0) { }
```

Comment: no, but keep in mind it is different for conditionals like `>==` and `<==`

Comment: The Yoda conditions programming style’s intent is to avoid unexpected behavior. It does so by forcing a syntax error when the programmer makes a typo by using an assignment operator (=) when s/he meant to do an equality operator.                                                                              
 if (0 == $something) // in case of type  0= $something you are safe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there is no difference in both performance wise or in functional perspective.  I can say it's a personal choice of coding style often called that as [**Yoda Style**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)

> In programming jargon, Yoda conditions (also called Yoda notation) is a programming style where the two parts of an expression are reversed in a conditional statement.

I prefer the later way as the first way kills the readability of code (*at least for me*)

Answer (score 1):

No,
there is absolutely no difference between the two as the if condition will check for equality between both sides.